# Простая игра на python. Как обратиться к элементу в доске, проверить его расположение и поменять на опр символ?

Tags: python

не понимаю, как из списка игровой доски достать опр элемент и проверить его номер + проверить лежит ли он наискосок от другого элемента, который ввёл другой игрок. Саму задачу вставил ниже, вот мой код на текущий момент : (поле у меня реализовано через * , 4 столбца по 5 элементов в каждом. Рассмотрю любые предложения. Загвоздка в том, что у каждого игрока из трёх свой уникальный символ, которым он заполняет поле и программа проверяет лежат ли они рядом или наискосок и добавляет штрафные баллы этим игрокам. PS буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь решит эту задачку, даже готов поддержать копеечкой...

```
board = ['*','*','*','*',]
def draw_board(board):
    print('-' * 21)
    for i in range(4):
        print("|", board[0], "|", board[0], "|", board[0], "|", board[0], "|", board[0], "|")
        print("-" * 21)
draw_board(board)

#изменение поля
def change_board(player_token):
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        player_move = input(f'Введите координаты хода(строка,столбец)')
        coordinate = player_move.split(',')
        y = int(coordinate[0])  # строка
        z = int(coordinate[1])  # столбец
        try:
            y = int(y)
            z = int(z)
        except:
            print('Введите числа через запятую!')
        if 1 <= y <= 5 and 1 <= z <= 4:
```

вывод доски:

```
---------------------
| * | * | * | * | * |
---------------------
| * | * | * | * | * |
---------------------
| * | * | * | * | * |
---------------------
| * | * | * | * | * |
---------------------
```

> Реализовать программу, при помощи которой 3 игрока могут играть в игру
> «Лоскутное одеяло». Правила игры следующие. На поле, имеющем размер 4
> на 5 клеток за один ход каждый игрок должен заполнить одну клетку
> своим символом. Игрок старается, чтобы его символы были как можно
> дальше друг от друга. В ходе игры ведется подсчет очков: за каждое
> соседство клеток с одинаковыми символами игроку, владельцу символа
> добавляется одно штрафное очко. Соседними считаются клетки, имеющие
> общую сторону или расположенные наискосок друг от друга. Выигрывает
> тот, у кого в конце игры меньше всего штрафных очков. Взаимодействие с
> программой производится через консоль. Игровое поле изображается в
> виде 4 текстовых строк и перерисовывается при каждом изменении
> состояния поля. При запросе данных от пользователя программа сообщает,
> что ожидает от пользователя (например, координаты очередного хода) и
> проверяет корректность ввода. Программа должна уметь автоматически
> определять количество штрафных очков и окончание партии и ее
> победителя.
> Сама программа НЕ ходит, т.е. не пытается заполнять клетки символами с целью выиграть
> игру.

Comment: Создать двумерный массив размером с поля и там отмечать ходы и проверять

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то вам необходимо после окончания игры просто пройтись по всем элементам введенной таблицы и для каждого элемента найти количество его соседей с таким же символом. В итоге для каждого игрока будет вычислено удвоенное количество пар его соседних элементов, которое нужно будет разделить на 2. Во время самой игры я советую вам ничего не считать - легко запутаться в том, посчитали ли вы уже эту пару или нет.

Comment: Да, можно и так. В задаче написано , чтобы программа должна была уметь автоматически определять количество штрафных очков и окончание партии и ее победителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table = [['*'] * 5 for _ in range(4)]
players_char = ['1', '2', '3']

for i in range(20):
    player = i % 3
    x, y = map(int, input(f'Ход игрока {player + 1}: ').split())
    table[y - 1][x - 1] = players_char[player]

dxy = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], \
       [0,  -1],          [0,  1], \
       [1,  -1], [1,  0], [1,  1]  ]
score = [0, 0, 0]
for y in range(4):
    for x in range(5):
        for i in range(len(dxy)):
            nx, ny = x + dxy[i][0], y + dxy[i][1]
            if 0 <= nx < 5 and 0 <= ny < 4:
                if table[y][x] == table[ny][nx]:
                    score[int(table[y][x]) - 1] += 1
                    # Для иных символов игроков нужно составить словарь
                    # char_rev = {player_char[i]: i for i in range(len(player))}
                    # И использовать score[char_rev[table[y][x]]]

# Теперь в score удвоенное количество штрафных очков каждого игрока
# Так что их все нужно поделить на 2
score = [i // 2 for i in score]

for i in range(len(player)):
    print(f'Игрок {i + 1} получил {score[i]} штрафных очков')

# Тут далее необходимо расписать возможные случаи:
# 1) Победил один игрок - у него меньше очков, чем у двух других
# 2) Победили два игрока - у них одинаковое количество очков, меньшее, чем у третьего
# 3) Полная ничья - у всех игроков одинаковое количество очков
# После чего вывести соответствующее сообщение о победе
```

Comment: Я писал программу прямо тут на SO, поэтому напишите, если в ней какие-то баги закрались - я поправлю. Надеюсь принцип обхода понятен, но если нет, то я также опишу его подробнее позже

Comment: Багов нету вроде,  всё нормально. Только добавить try except , чтобы прога не выключалась с ошибкой и перерисовку поля. Только не могу понять, а как сделать "интерактивный режим" чтобы прога каждый раз выводила и кол-во очков у пользователей и изменённое поле при каждом ходе? А потом, когда все поля будут заполнены посчитать кол-во итоговый очков у пользователя и вывести победителя.

Comment: Когда я делал массив понял, что прога будет считать соседние элементы даже если они в других столбцах на выводе (т.е выходить за рамки самого поля)

Comment: @Matvey Интерактивный режим можно сделать, если после каждого хода считать, сколько вокруг поставленного элемента таких же, после чего прибавлять это число к счету текущего игрока. А что вы имеете в виду под выходом за границы поля? В моей проге координаты проверяются, так что проблем с этим быть не должно.

Comment: File "C:/Users/79268/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/games.py", line 41, in <module>
    score[int(table[y][x]) - 1] += 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*'

вот такая ошибка вылезает уже под конец игры

Comment: Хм, странно. Вы уверены, что пользователи сделали 20 различных ходов? Потому что звездочек в конечном массиве остаться не должно было. Или вы написали интерактивную версию?

Comment: На вашем чистом коде так и происходит почему-то,  я лишь пока что написал функцию для вывода поля каждый раз при вводе координат хода. Сижу вот думаю, что к чему..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113620/discussion-between-ezikbro-and-matvey).